# Extract first file only in RAR archive

Tags: macos, unix, archive, unrar

I want to use Alexander Roshal's Unrar 5.21 under Mac OS X to extract only the first file (of which I do not know the name) of a given archive.
Since all the files in the archive are jpg, the following gives me name of the first file:

```
unrar t test.rar | sed -n '7s_Testing  *\(.*\)\.jpg.*$_\1\.jpg_pg'
```

However, putting this into a variable and running unrar again just seems absurdly clumsy.

Is there a direct way to extract the first (or, more generally, the n-th) file of a given rar archive using the command line? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This does the job:

```
unrar e test.rar "$(unrar vb test.rar | sed -n 1p)"
```